# Bounding a summation by a geometric series

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

I was going through the math/appendix section of the [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) book and encountered this proof for bounding by a geometric series:

[image]

**And the things that i don't quite understand are:**

1. If ak+1 / ak <= r and if a2 = 2 and a3 = 3 then how does 0<r<1 hold?
2. If the answer to Q1 is that it holds only for a decreasing arithmetic series then how does the summation symbol imply that ?
3. What is the difference between bounding each term and bounding the sum of the series?
4. How is ak <= a0rk ? Is it a fundamental theorem ?

> I know there are many questions here and if you can answer even a single one that would mean a lot because that at least brings me to the right path. Even answer to just references to articles or videos online that can help solve the issue is greatly appreciated.

> Thank you :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 0<r<1 would not hold for the example you give here, as 3/2>1. The bounds on r are a precondition on using this method of bounding with a decreasing geometric series. In other words, you can only bound with a decreasing geometric series (using this method) if there exists a constant r between 0 and 1 such that the ratio between successive terms is smaller than the constant r.
2. The condition on the ratio of successive terms in the sequence being between 0 and 1 does mean that the sequence is decreasing.
3. Bounding each term is a way of bounding the series. If every term is smaller than the corresponding term of another series, then the sum of the former will be smaller than the sum of the latter. That's what is happening here: the first inequality claims that the sum of the series on the left is bounded by the sum of the series on the right because each term (up to n) on the left is less or equal to than each corresponding term on the right (and after n, adding positive values retains the inequality).
4. This is because of the assumption that the ratio of successive terms of a_k is always less than or equal to r. It follows directly from this assumption that a_(k+1) < (a_k)r for every k, which means that a_k < a_0(r^k).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and the time :D u explained question 1 to 3 but i had to look at the second answers for 4th question .. maybe im very dumb at skipping steps but thank you so so muh nonetheless :D

Answer (score 2):

You are given the following.

> ***suppose that***   `a_(k+1)/a_k <= r`   where   `0 < r < 1`

There must be an additional assumption stated somewhere that all terms are non-negative `a_k >= 0`, otherwise the conclusion does not follow. Then...

> If `a_(k+1)/ak <= r` and if `a2=2` and `a3=3` then ...

No sequence that satisfies the given condition can start with `a2=2` and `a3=3`.

This cannot happen because the problem statement for `k=2` is that `a3/a2 <= r < 1`, while your values give `a3/a2 = 3/2 > 1`.

> If the answer to Q1 is that it holds only for a decreasing arithmetic series then how does the summation symbol imply that ?

It does not. The summation symbol does not indicate anything about the terms of the series. But the statement of the problem presumes `a_(k+1)/a_k <= r < 1` which for non-negative numbers implies `a_(k+1) < a_k` so the sequence of terms is strictly decreasing.

> What is the difference between bounding each term and bounding the sum of the series?

The former implies the latter by simply adding the inequalities. For example, if you know that `a1 <= b1` and `a2 <= b2` then you can derive that `a1+a2 <= b1+b2`.

> How is a_k <= a0 r^k ? Is it a fundamental theorem?

`a_k <= r a_(k-1)` and `a_(k-1) <= r a_(k-2)`, so `a_k <= r a_(k-1) <= r^2 a_(k-2)`. Repeat to obtain `a_k <= r^3 a(k-3) <= r^4 a_(k-4) <= ... <= r^k a_0`.

Comment: im sorry its not im not responding im just having a hard time understanding because i think i got my fundamentals mistaken.

Comment: @AaryanDhakal Not a problem, and feel free to ask for further clarification where needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answers .. im new to this so i had a hard time understanding the 3 first question as im not that great at lingo but the last answer was very 'BABY STEP'ish which is why i loved it and understood it clearly thank you so much :D